# How to load space delimited file as a collection item in hive?

Tags: hive

I am new to hive and I am having problem loading a file with space 
delimited as a array.
 my source file:

```
   Manjeet,1 1 1 1 1 5 10 20 10 10 10 20 5 5 10 1 1 1 1 1 5 10 10 10
   Ron,1 1 1 1 1 5 10 20 10 10 10 10
   Ron,1 1 5 1 10 5 10 20 10 20 1 1 10 10 10
   Pat,1 1 1 1 1 5 10 20 10 10 10 10 10 10
```

I tried the following command:

```
  create table teller
  (Name string, Bill array<string>)
  Row format delimited
  Fields terminated by ','
  Collection items terminated by ''
  Lines terminated by '\n'
  Stored as textfile
  location '/user/training/hive/Bank';
```

I get this:

```
  Manjeet ["1 1 1 1 1 5 10 20 10 10 10 20 5 5 10 1 1 1 1 1 5 10 10 10"]
  Ron     ["1 1 1 1 1 5 10 20 10 10 10 10"]
  Ron     ["1 1 5 1 10 5 10 20 10 20 1 1 10 10 10"]
  Pat     ["1 1 1 1 1 5 10 20 10 10 10 10 10 10"]
```

i Want the result to be like

```
  Manjeet ["1","1","1","1","1", "5"} and so on...
```

Comment: i think it should be `Collection items terminated by ' '`(note the `space`)

Comment: Thanks you! that worked, I thought ' ' is space.